# Replace for-loop by function

Tags: r, function, for-loop, apply

I have the following for-loop, which creates a dummy variable for each level in the Code variable, which I want to write as a function so I can use it in an apply-function:

```
for(level in data$Letters){
  data[paste(level, sep="")] <- ifelse(data$Letters == level, 1, 0)
}
```

Here is an example on how my data looks like (original data frame is much larger):

```
Letters <- c("A","B","C")
Numbers <- c(1,0,1)
Numbers <- as.integer(Numbers)

data <- data.frame(Letters,Numbers)
```

And here is what I am looking for:

```
Result <- matrix(c(1,0,0,
                   0,1,0,
                   0,0,1),3,3)
Final <- cbind(data,Result)
```

Is there a way to rewrite the for-loop as a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `outer` for this:

```
with(data, outer(Letters, levels(Letters), "=="))*1
#        [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]    1    0    0
#  [2,]    0    1    0
#  [3,]    0    0    1
```

... and to nicely `cbind` it with your original data frame, you might do something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Letters,Numbers) 
# better to avoid using `data` as a name for a data frame
df2 <- with(df, outer(Letters, levels(Letters), "=="))*1 
cbind(df, setNames(as.data.frame(df2), levels(df$Letters)))
#   Letters Numbers A B C
# 1       A       1 1 0 0
# 2       B       0 0 1 0
# 3       C       1 0 0 1
```

Alternatively, you can use `sapply`:

```
sapply(levels(df$Letters), function(x) df$Letters==x)*1
# notice that the result is a matrix rather than a data frame
# but it is still safe to cbind it to a data frame:
cbind(df, sapply(levels(df$Letters), function(x) df$Letters==x)*1)
```

`lapply` could be used as well but in this case, it appears that `sapply` labels the columns automatically but `lapply` does not, so you would have to do it manually with setNames, for example:

```
as.data.frame(lapply((function(.) setNames(.,.)) (levels(df$Letters)), function(x) (df$Letters==x)*1))
```

... or step by step:

```
N <- levels(df$Letters)
N <- setNames(N,N)
out <- lapply(N, "==", df$Letters)
out <- as.data.frame(out)*1
```